# sed to add new line after character

Tags: linux

Is there away to add new line after matching certain characters in string using sed command?
Here is my input string {"foo" = "foovalue","bar" = "barvalue"}
Need output like this:

```
{
  "foo" = "foovalue",
  "bar" = "barvalue"
}
```

Tried with this but no luck. sed 's/{},/\n' test.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a bit closer to the expected output with

```
sed 's/\([,{]\)/\1\n/g;s/}/\n}/g'
```

But there's a problem: the indentation doesn't work, and it gets even worse if there are nested objects or arrays (think JSON with `=` instead of `:`).

If there's no nesting, you can just indent any line not starting with a curly brace:

```
sed 's/\([,{]\)/\1\n/g;s/}/\n}/g;' test.txt | sed '/^[{}]/!s/^/  /'
```

It can still fail if a comma or a curly brace appears double quoted.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `sed` is below. I am not sure if it works for your general case but for the example you give this just works.

```
echo '{"foo" = "foovalue","bar" = "barvalue"}' | tr '=' ':' | jq | tr ':' '='

# output:
{
  "foo"= "foovalue",
  "bar"= "barvalue"
}
```

You need to install `jq` for this. In ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install jq
```